how I can customize font color using conditional format in openxlsx2 in r?
Hi and thanks for reading me
Im currently working in an excel file with a conditional format using R and the package openxlsx2, but when I add the style I get an error in the document output. My code is:
library(openxlsx2)

wb_workbook(creator = "Jorge Hernandez", title = "accounts MX summarise", category = "sales") |>
  wb_add_worksheet("Evolucion", gridLines = F, tabColor = "#4e6fa3") |>
  wb_add_data(
    x = iris
  ) |> 
  wb_add_conditional_formatting(type = "expression",
                                cols = 1:ncol(iris),
                                rows = 2:200,
                                style = create_dxfs_style(font_color = wb_color(hex = "FF9C6500"),
                                                          bgFill = wb_color(hex = "FFFFEB9C")),
                                rule = ">0" ) |> 
  wb_save(
    path = "/Users/jorgehca/Desktop/data.xlsx"
  )

does anyone knows how I can apply the font color and background color for cell style correctly?

You have to assign the dxf style first:
library(openxlsx2)

wb_workbook(
  creator = "Jorge Hernandez",
  title = "accounts MX summarise",
  category = "sales"
) |>
  wb_add_worksheet(
    "Evolucion",
    grid_lines = FALSE,
    tab_color = "#4e6fa3"
  )|>
  wb_add_data(
    x = iris
  ) |> 
  wb_add_dxfs_style(
    name = "Jorges_CF_style",
    font_color = wb_color(hex = "FF9C6500"),
    bg_fill = wb_color(hex = "FFFFEB9C")
  ) |>
  wb_add_conditional_formatting(
    type = "expression",
    cols = seq_along(iris),
    rows = 2:200,
    style = "Jorges_CF_style",
    rule = ">0" 
  ) |>
  wb_save(temp_xlsx())

It's like this, because it allows you to reuse conditional formatting styles and allows you to use dxf styles that have been loaded.
